# Inserting records to ContentFolder and ContentWorkspace

Tags: apex, soql, metadata-api, tooling-api

Good day!

I wanted to programmatically create a library. Manually in lightning mode you need to navigate to **Files** tab and then choose **Libraries** and then click the New Library button. Supply a name and description and then your library is created.

I noticed this action is inserting records in **ContentWorkspace** and in **ContentFolder**. I am just not sure if it is inserting in any other table.

My questions is, can I normally insert via soql in apex? Or do I need to use an external api tool(MetadataAPI or ToolingAPI) for this? I also wanted to know the involved object for this so is there any reference for the connections of such?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use APIs (to keep this very simple) you can:

- Create a folder using [ContentFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ContentFolder)
- You can then create a [Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Document) and give it the Folder ID

However if you are trying to do this programmatically - I assume you mean via Apex?
In which case you can create these via Apex (there are a couple of ways to do this, [here is an example of using Connect API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_add_repository_item_binary.htm))

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't use the ConnectApi object but instead a raw http request using the REST Api in one of your links.